# In Python, ignore digits in string but remove pure digits

Tags: python, regex

I am processing string like

> This is python3 and learning it takes 100 hours

I want to remove only digits like 100 but want to keep digits when it is part of anything like python3.

I am trying the regex

```
text = re.sub('[0-9]', '', text)
```

but it is not working as expected. Help is appreciated.

Comment: You may now think about accepting an answer or comment one to get details ;) to reward those who spent time for you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add a space to both sides of your regex, and then have a single space as the replacement.  Remember to also a `+` to match one or more digits:

```
import re

text = 'This is python3 and learning it takes 100 hours'
text = re.sub(r' [0-9]+ ', ' ', text)
print(text)
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> This is python3 and learning it takes hours
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try below,

```
text = re.sub(' [0-9]{1,} ', ' ', text)
```

Comment: This will not capture digits from `100 hours learning required`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\b` word boundary (class `\d` is for `[0-9]`) :

```
def clean(value):
    return re.sub(r"\b\d+\b", "", value)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(clean("This is python3 and learning it takes 100 hours"))  # This is python3 and learning it takes  hours
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/elrZOC/2)